# Restrict VO execution On Page Load

Tags: oracle-adf

I have a VO on a page which is displayed as a Table.
So when the Page Loads the VO gets automatically executed and the data is displayed on the page as soon as the page loads.
Can I stop the execution of the VO on page load?
I would like to have the table with no data displayed when the page loads.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a query with a parameter in the business definition. In this paramater you can choose to show or not to show data for example

```
select * from dual where 1 = :parameter
```

During the page load you can set parameter to 0 so that the query will result in a blank set. Then inside the page you can put a command button or link to execute the query sending the parameter valued in 1 so that the query result comes complete.

Comment: I have tried this already but the thing is as the query gets executed its takes a bit time for the page to load, If i can stop the execution of the vo on load the problem will be solved

Comment: Maybe then you can use a trick. Yu can have two view objects one with an empty resultset and other with the populated resuldset. And change the model of the table in the jspx using a bean.

Comment: some other ideas - https://blogs.oracle.com/shay/entry/preventing_queries_when_page_f   http://andrejusb.blogspot.com/2009/08/oracle-adf-tuning-preventing-sql-query.html

Answer (score 0):

The proper(as designed/intended by ADF) way to do this is to add an AF:query component or AF:quickquery component.
This prevents the query from executing and displaying.
Once the user enters something and executes the query, the target ui component (form, table, etc) will refresh with the contents.
af:query component is based on a ViewCrieria that you build in the VO. A viewcriteria is a named where clause fragment.

The af:quickquery component allows the user to select one of several attributes and execute a query.
Far easier than the suggested approach by User2505647

These may help:
[afquery](http://jdevadf.oracle.com/adf-richclient-demo/docs/tagdoc/af_query.html)